# What's wrong with using int variable ? Making the application to crash

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my MainActivity.java
I used // to mark as not using on some lines and found that the line start with int t =
Is the problem that make the application to crash and force closing.

```
package com.example.camera_test;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );

            startActivityForResult( intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST );
        }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  
        // do something
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            int t = thumbnail.getByteCount();
            TextView age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            age.setText(Integer.toString(t));
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }  
       }  
}
```

I added a button when I click on it it will open the camera on my device after I take a photo it will show the photo I took on a small window. It's working.

Then I added this 3 lines:

```
int t = thumbnail.getByteCount();
TextView age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
age.setText(Integer.toString(t));
```

I wanted to show also the ByteCount of the image on screen in my device.

Once I add the line: int t = thumbnail.getByteCount(); there was an error so I did automatic fix and it added @SuppressLint("NewApi")

Then I marked with // this 3 lines once I unmarked and used the line int t = thumbnail.getByteCount(); so after I took a photo it crashed and told me it need to force close.

Why does it crash on this line ?

This is the file activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="Activate The Camera" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

1. I can't figure out why it crash with the int t line.
2. I added a breakpoint on the int t line but it never stop there and never stop anywhere on my application when I add a breakpoint why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  getByteCount() is available from API level 12 (android 3.1+).
Are you sure you are building/running this version or above?

Also please add LogCat in the feature, much easier to find the error.

Comment: Nicklas for now I changed the int t line to: ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
         byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
         int size = ba.length;
         TextView age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         age.setText(Integer.toString(size));

Comment: And it's working showing it to me. But how do I change I mean where in Eclipse I change the API level to 12 or above ? And if im doing the change will this application run later on lower api levels I mean lower then Android 3.1 ?

Comment: I see when im running the application that the target is 2.2

Comment: If you use API functionalities that are higher the will not run on lower versions. Yet some higher API functions are possible to use since they are ignored on lower versions, like manifest attributes such as installLocation etc. If your other solution works with lower versions then you should use it if you want to support those versions.

Comment: You may also check the version the device is running during runtime and determina if you should use the "new" or "old" version of calculating the bytes. Something like
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1 ) { }
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#HONEYCOMB_MR1